# Changing Grails GSP variable markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, gsp

Is there a way to change the gsp variable markers ${somevar} to something like [% somevar %], i'm having a problem using jquery templates because they use ${somevar} also and the gsp tries to render those as grails variables which crashes the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had such problem too, with jQuery Tmpl + Grails. After some investigations I found a way to accomplish this, by using:

```
<%='${somevar}'%>
```

this `<%= %>` just prints value as is. Notice `''` are used there, it's a string values.

So, you GSP will be looking like:

```
<div class="item_<%='${index}'%>"><%='${data}'%></div>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, i had tried wrapping the whole jquery template block in <%= """   code   """ %>   but that turned the ${val} into a 'null' which seems odd to me, but it also didn't throw an error

Answer (score 2):

Rather than changing how I do things for Grails, I solved this by using the alternative jquery-template markup...

```
{{= somejQueryTemplateVar}}
```